# How to assign values in an Angular form without an input element or hiding the UI element?

Tags: angular, angular-ui, angular-ui-select

I am working on this template-driven form, where I have a dropdown.

The dropdown has an **ID** as value and **Name** as the display value.

When I submit the form, I need both the values **ID** and **Name** to be in the form output

```
   <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>State</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="data.stateCode" name="StateCode" #yddfyty>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let state of stateOptions" [value]="state.ID">
                {{state.name}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

After submitting the form, I get a JSON

```
{
  StateCode: "Option I select in the Dropdown"
}
```

When I submit the form, I also want the StateName to be in the form output.

How do I assign the StateName selected in the Dropdown, to a model property in the template-driven form?

I can think of a way where we can use an  element and hide the element, Is there any other way?

Is the only way to do it in the Typescript file after submitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewChild` comes handy in these situations:

HTML File:

```
<mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>State</mat-label>
            <mat-select  name="StateCode" #ElementRef>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let state of stateOptions" [value]="state.ID">
                {{state.name}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

Component TS File:

first declare an viewchild variable:

```
@ViewChild('ElementRef') stateElement: any;
```

and later on you can use this variable when you submit the form:

```
    OnSubmit(){
     let selectedStateCode = this.stateElement.nativeElement.value//selected dropdown value
     let selectedStateText = this.stateElement.nativeElement.textContent //selected dropdown text
     //rest of your submit code;
    }
```

Comment: This makes sense, thanks! Please add to your answer if you get a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the given restrictions you will have to handle the form submit in `.ts` file.